# Cat D11 calibration

Tags: technic, motor

Once I start the calibration of the Cat D11 does anyone know how long it should take? I have let mine run for at least 10 minutes and it never completes. Should I keep it going for more time? Or is something wrong?

Comment: Just curious if you made any progress? My son, who is 11 just finished the build and the blade, hook on the back and ladder lifts. And then all the gears seem to spin. Any suggestions. Thanks